# Cannot access database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi i need some help in coding php to connect database
my source code is

```
$host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 

$username="root"; // Mysql username 

$password=""; // Mysql password 

$db_name="test"; // Database name 

$tbl_name="forum_question"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
`mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";`
```

But it display error

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\123\tryforum\main_forum.php on line 11
>   cannot select DB

How to solve it

Comment: Have you read the error message and the respective documentation?

Comment: thank you for the reminder. i've seen it and it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass connection variable to mysqli_select_db.
[See this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp)

```
$host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 

$username="root"; // Mysql username 

$password=""; // Mysql password 

$db_name="test"; // Database name 

$tbl_name="forum_question"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($con, "$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";`
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

> needs two parameter first your database connection and second your
>   database name

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($sql);

Comment: Use `$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` check updated answer